# Nextjs state size affecting performance and lag in state update

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, filesize, state-management

In **Nextjs** when i save huge size data in the **state**, for example 50mb the state update speed is very low, and reducing the site permormance. Is there any solution to fix it i'm searching for 2 days. **Thanks in advance**.

Answer (score 0):

Saving this amount of data in a single state might not be a good practice.

I suggest:

1- Spread the global state (can also be referred to as any parent state) into multiple local states (component states).

2- Only save the necessary data in the state (if you are using a state management library such as redux only save the really shared state which most likely will be some UI state), There are multiple types of states consider checking the following [article](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-state-types) for more details.

3- Use a data-fetching library such as React-Query you can benefit from the caching behavior that can play a similar role to a shared state.

Comment: I'm using local state, in a single page i need to store more than 100MB data for multiple file upload. I'm storing file blob, name, type and some other fields in the same state as array of objects. can i store files on different state and other fields on the seperate state. Will it increase the performance?

Comment: Is there any strong reason why you would want to store this huge amount of data in your state? if by any chance it's coming from API have you considered pagination? 
To answer your question "Will it increases the performance?", If you use one of the two states more than the other then definitely separate them. and if there is some state that you only need in child components you should move them to that component instead of top-level parent to avoid unnecessary re-rendering.

Comment: Consider using transition which was introduced on react 18 https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usetransition
for non-priority state update, it basically tells react to priorities certain state updates (and rerendering) over others

Answer (score 0):

Please create a thumbnail for the video and image for eg 300x300 and display it. It will not have lag time. Once you have to send to server send the blob of original acquired state.

Hope it helpss!!